# How to use ActiveSupport::Inflector with Cyrillic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, activesupport, cyrillic

`ActiveSupport::Inflector` methods like `titleize`, `capitalize`, `camelize` do not work with Cyrillic (Russian, Belarussian, Ukraine, ...) letters.

```
'xyz'.titleize         
 # => "Xyz"              # OK
'абв'.titleize         
 # => "АБВ"              # FAIL
```

How can I use `ActiveSupport::Inflector` methods with Cyrillic letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [mb_chars](http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars) to "save" **Cyrillic** string then `ActiveSupport::Inflector`  methods should work:

```
'абв'.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
 => "Абв"
```